# How long does it take to get a green card post EB5 visa?

Tags: usa, visa, greencard, pr

This is in accordance with the EB5 investor visa where someone who invests at least $500k or $1M in a US-based business

Answer (score 5):

The EB-5 visa is an immigrant visa, so the visa itself becomes a temporary green card when the bearer of the visa first arrives in the US.  The permanent green card arrives subsequently in the mail.  This can take [up to 120 days](https://egov.uscis.gov/processing-times/expect-green-card) from the date of entry or the date of payment of the immigrant visa fee, whichever is later.